# Edit/Update data from SQL in a MATRIX/CROSSTAB

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, grid, pivot, crosstab

I have a table as follows:

```
userid, customer id, date
```

the table holds data like

```
0001, 1000, 12/12/2014
0001, 1002, 12/12/2014
0001, 1003, 12/12/2014
0001, 1004, 12/12/2014

0002, 2000, 12/12/2014
0002, 2001, 12/12/2014
0002, 2002, 12/12/2014
0002, 2003, 12/12/2014
```

so it holds customers for a specific users for a specific date..

now I want to display this information in a grid view for a specific user (updatable with check boxes) in asp.net

```
customer id       12/1 - 12/2 -  12/3 -   12/4
1000              X        X       X        X
1001              X        X                 X 
1002              X        X       X
1003              X                  X       X
1004              X                  X       X
```

where there is record in db a checked checkbox will appear. I want the grid to be updatable so that if I check any new boxes and update it should add records to the table,

What is the best possible way to achieving this in  asp.net? any ready-made control/grid that I can use to achieve this?

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a comment so i am going to write something here. Why don't use the PIVOT clouse and prepare your data in the SQL query and simply show in the app.
If you need to edit your data i think that you will have write more fancy sql to update the data. If you don't need the real time data or your data is not updating in other way than your app you can make a copy (or make copy daily) and store your data in the format that you want

Comment: actually as u said the pivot will do for display but the big problem is on updating it back to DB!